# Self answering OkCupid posts, on topic? spam?

Tags: discussion, moderation

A new (to Web Apps) user has posted and answered minutes later a couple of questions about the 'OKCupid' dating site. [One](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29015/how-can-i-get-okcupid-search-to-show-only-matches-within-5-miles-of-me), [two](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29018/how-can-i-find-a-cuddle-friend-on-okcupid).

It could be some sort of advertising, or a super keen user. To be honest I'm not even sure how the topic site itself falls within the guidelines here - it isn't really adult content but does it qualify as an app?

I'm curious to know what others make of it an how welcome it is here.

Answer (score 3):

OKCupid is a web application, listings are not static and the information is dynamically updated with a feed in a similar format to how Facebook/LinkedIn/Twitter updates their posts. The adult content is near non existent on the site, that is,

You will have to look for it to find it, in the same way one may:

- stumble across a nude Tumblr blog
- stumble across a porn star Twitter profile
- read the casual connections on Craigslist

Not that I am advocating adult content on the site more that I am saying it is fully possible to answer the question while removing the parts that prove to be age restricted to keep it in scope.

Seeing that the user already has a regular profile on https://judaism.stackexchange.com/ I don't see how any spamming could be occurring.

This is just a case of a user having information that at one point, he may have been trying to find, self-answered himself and decided to share with others.

Answer (score 1):

While these two questions could be legitimate they do smell a lot like spam/astroturfing. The subject matter is not explicitly off topic, but as it deals with adult relationships I can see how some people might object. I have no view one way or the other.

I've left comments on both to encourage the user to declare any interest they might have in the site and make them aware of the rules we have over this sort of thing. We'll have to keep an eye on things to make sure that it all falls within the scope of the site.

Just as a note, there is nothing intrinsically wrong with answering your own question. It's even encouraged now with the addition of the ability to post your answer with the question.

Comment: I'm aware self-answering isn't an issue, especially with the Q&A checkbox now, more worried about possible spam and if dating sites are web apps!

Comment: @JohnC - sorry. Misread that bit of the question.